# Google Translate is removing CSS

Tags: css, google-translate

I've added googles translate app to a site using the following
code

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    autoDisplay: false,
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}

</script><script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?
cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

The app seems to work for a couple of languages. When translating to other
languages all the css is removed.

I'm keeping an eye on specific elements (such as a li in the header, or a div), and then running the translation. I can see that neither the header scripts (ie the css), or the elements are being changed by the app. It's just that the styles are no long applied (firebug tells me 'This element has no style rules')

The problem occurs on Firefox but not Chrome or Opera.

Any ideas what's going on here?

[image: afrikaans tranlsation]
[image: french translation]

Comment: please show your web page as an example.

Comment: I've added a couple of images.

Comment: not much use, for me at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same issue -

The php that compresses the css files was adding a title to the scripts so

```
<link title="Default" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/modules/pd_smoothgallery/jd.gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

was being changed to

```
<link title="Par défaut" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/modules/pd_smoothgallery/jd.gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I removed the title and the translation works fine for all languages.

(not sure why firebug wasn't highlighting this change, but it wasn't).

Comment: Even better - add 'class="notranslate"' to the link element.

Answer (score 0):

```
#google_translate_element span{
     color:white!important;
     font-size:15px;
     border-left:1px solid transparent!important;
     line-height: 22px;
 }  
 .goog-te-gadget-simple {
    background-color: #5191CD !important;
     border-left: 1px solid transparent !important; 
     border-top: 1px solid transparent !important; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent!important; 
    border-right: 1px solid transparent !important;
 } 
 .goog-te-gadget-icon {
     margin-left: 0px; 
     margin-right: 0px; 
    width: 0px!important; 
     height: 0px !important; 
    border: none; 
     vertical-align: middle; 
}
```